# Small issue with a differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have the following problem

$y'y'' - 3(y')^2=y^{2}y''$

In order to solved I made the following substitution $y'=z(y)$ in other words $y'=z$ and $z=z(y)$.

After taking the derivative of $y'=z(y)$ and playing with the chain rule I obtained

$y'' = y'\frac{dz}{dy}$

replacing this into the equation leaves us with.

$z^2\frac{dz}{dy}-3z^2 = y^2z\frac{dz}{dy}$

At this point I'm unable to solve due to some conceptual errors. I know I can get my equation to the form of an exact problem. For instance say I divide by $\frac{dz}{dy}$. I can then re-arrange the problem into

$3z^2\frac{dy}{dz} = z^2 - y^2z$

$3z dy = dz(z-y^2)$

However, because of how I defined my substitution earlier  $y'=z(y)$ in other words $y'=z$ and $z=z(y)$. I do not know how my partial derivatives would look in order to solve this by exact. Can I please get an explanation on how I could solve this/example/solution. Thank you

### EDIT

Due to many comments calling out for a typo I choose to upload some of my assigned problems. Perhaps they can help shed light on the topic. From what I know in order to solve these, we need some kind of substitution/power reduction.

Out of these problems so far I have only been able to solve "h" after diving by x and making a substitution saying $z = \frac{y'}{x}$. How would I be able to solve for the others?

[image]

Comment: Are you sure the original statement is written correctly? $$y'y'' - 3(y')^2=y^{2}y''$$

Comment: @Moo, It is correct. Should $y^2$ not be there this would reduce to separable.

Comment: I don't see how it is solvable in closed form as currently written. You'd have to use numerical methods.

Comment: @Moo, Thanks for trying. Let me know if you have any alternative methods or so.

Comment: Are you sure it's not $$\color {red }{yy''} - 3(y')^2=y^{2}y''$$ This one is integrable.

Comment: @LostInSpace sadly, I am sure.

Comment: I bet for a typo in the book

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici Is this specific to this problem or problems with in a format similar to this one? I will edit my problem soon with other exercises my professor has posted  to compare.